# Docker php image is looking for windows paths on macos

Tags: php, macos, docker, apache

I have used PHP images for development purposes for quite a long time and one day I'm starting my app and what do I see?: EXITED: 254.

Logs:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext/bz2 (C:\xampp\php\ext/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), C:\xampp\php\ext/bz2.so (C:\xampp\php\ext/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Unable to start standard module in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

As you see something is looking for Windows paths but I'm using Linux containers on MacOs. Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on here?

Dockerfile (dominikgubrynowicz/php-mysqli-8.0)

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: mi19-project
    image: dominikgubrynowicz/php-mysqli-8.0
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty
        MARIADB_USER: dominik
        MARIADB_PASSWORD: qwerty
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details. How did you configure PHP? Also, how is this related to Apache?

Comment: I'm using just `php:8.0-apache` image with the default configuration. https://hub.docker.com/_/php